# FFMPEG encoder:Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am encoding video with h264 codec and mp4 container. The source is a sequence of images I load from memory. The encoding seems to be working good. I am able to verify the exact amount of frames encoded, but what bugs me is the following warning/error I am getting at the end of the session from the muxer in terminal:

> Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to
> muxer in stream 0:

I tried different techniques to calculate pts/dts and it is the same. I did notice though, that `avcodec_receive_packet()` sometimes returns packets out of order,so may be that's the reason for the warning? Below is my function where I encode the image data.

```
bool LibAVEncoder::EncodeFrame(uint8_t* data)
{

int err;
if (!mVideoFrame)//init frame once
{
    mVideoFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    mVideoFrame->format = mVideoStream->codecpar->format;
    mVideoFrame->width = mCodecContext->width;
    mVideoFrame->height = mCodecContext->height;
    if ((err = av_frame_get_buffer(mVideoFrame, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate picture: %i\n", err); 
        return false;
    }
}

err = av_frame_make_writable(mVideoFrame);
if (!mSwsCtx)
{
    mSwsCtx = sws_getContext(mCodecContext->width, mCodecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, mCodecContext->width,
        mCodecContext->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
}

const int inLinesize[1] = { 4 * mCodecContext->width };

// RGBA to YUV
sws_scale(mSwsCtx, (const uint8_t* const*)&data, inLinesize, 0, mCodecContext->height, mVideoFrame->data, mVideoFrame->linesize);

mVideoFrame->pts = mFrameCount++;
 
 //Encoding
err = avcodec_send_frame(mCodecContext, mVideoFrame);
if (err < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to send frame: %i\n", err);
    return false;
}

while (err >= 0)
{

    err = avcodec_receive_packet(mCodecContext, mPacket);
    if (err == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (err == AVERROR_EOF)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (err < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding,shutting down\n");
        exit(1);
    }

      // 1. way of calc pts/dts
    mPacket->pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(mPacket->pts, mCodecContext->time_base, mVideoStream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    mPacket->dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(mPacket->dts, mCodecContext->time_base, mVideoStream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    mPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(mPacket->duration, mCodecContext->time_base, mVideoStream->time_base);


  /*    
    //2. another way of calc pts/dts
    const int64_t duration = av_rescale_q(1, mCodecContext->time_base, mVideoStream->time_base);
    mPacket->duration = duration;
    mPacket->pts = totalDuration; 
    mPacket->dts = totalDuration;
    totalDuration += duration;
 */

     mPacket->stream_index = mVideoStream->index;
     av_interleaved_write_frame(mOFormatContext, mPacket);
     av_packet_unref(mPacket);   
 }
  return true;
}
```

I would appreciate any pointer to what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Same here! No response from anyone from ffmpeg. Is it deadth ?!

Comment: Probably all those who use FFMPEG libs directly have retired  ;)

Comment: What are the time bases you are using to rescale? It seems that you could get the same result for the dts for differetn frames after rescaling and rounding.